# Use of String.join in Constant Expression

Tags: java, compile-time-constant, constant-expression

I have a very long `String` constant which is used for an annotation, and this string is essentially a comma separated list. What I would like to be able to do is the following:

```
String str = String.join(", ", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl");

@Annotation(str)
public void foo();
```

But I get the error `element value must be a constant expression`. I understand that the expression does not fit into Java's definition of a constant expression, however, is there any way to assert to the compiler that `str` is constant? The code is much easier to read and maintain if I can write it in the above fashion (the actual list is much longer in my actual code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

A constant expression has [a precise definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) in the language spec, and anything involving a method invocation is not a constant expression.

The only way you could make this a constant expression would be by generating code containing the result of that method, compiling it, and using the constant-valued expression from that.

Comment: Darn. It'd be convenient if the compiler were able to special case certain expressions, but there may very well be a reason that's not possible.

Comment: @SamuelBarr there’s ongoing research in that direction, see https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/303#Constant-propagation and https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/constables.html#constant-tracking-propagation-and-folding